# Can't put a breakpoint in Angular constructor or OnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

I have an Angular application, and I am trying to set a breakpoint in <kbd>F12</kbd> tools in Chrome or IE. I have simple test case:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    message: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) { 
        console.log("Login Constructor");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Login OnInit");
    }
}
```

I see log output in the console, but setting a breakpoint doesn't work. I think it stopped working a few days ago (not sure if it was an upgrade of some library, or Windows, or both browsers). Don't even know where to start looking. The project is built with webpack, and I am getting to this component via routing:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: '/login',
    component: LoginComponent
}
...
]
```

Note, that button click handler breaks as expected.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? better add the tag to get better help. Meanwhile, check for the map file, if it is TS and missing map file, the debugger can't figure out where in the JS file this line goes to... try rebuild the JS file.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion - added typescript tag. map file is there, and I can see source code perfectly (that's how I can put breakpoint in the first place). And if I put a breakpoint in the code that gets executed *after* the page is loaded, it works fine

Comment: As a workaround, you can also just write [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger); to the code itself

Comment: OUCH! Completely forgot about this. Yes, debugger breaks! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's missing to breakpoint because a debugger doesn't know the location of the source code or the code is executing faster than debugger can imagine a breakpoint. In this case the code is not debuggable.

However you can set breakpoint directly to the transplitted javascript code if you can understand the javascript. Webpack sometimes writes a wrong path to the sources in the map file, so you have a lot troubles to fix them. But this issue outgoing from the original question. What you have to do is to try a different browser or version of Webpack where the bugs are fixed. If you know it a bug you should submit it to the corresponding bugtracking system.

Comment: It *feels* that as you said the code gets executed faster than debugger. At least the web page gets displayed before source code in F12. Webpack keeps everything in memory; there aren't really physical javascript files that I can analyze. I'll try to build a minimal project based on Angular heroes that I can share...

Comment: I don't need it, everyone angular developer knows that debugger doesn't work in some cases, but nobody says why. The project might depend on environment where it's running and results became local to that environment.